# DB2 Windows Time Function (The System cannot accept the time entered)

Tags: windows, db2

I am doing a Data Concurrency, Locking activity and running a time command in DB2 Command Line to quantify the wait time in executing the query.

Code:

```
> C:\Program File\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN>time db2 "Select * from tb1"
> The system cannot accept the time entered.
> Enter the new time:
```

How can I fix this? I tried to enter a time but it wont display the elapsed time of the query

I'm really new in DB2 and I'm super not familiar with the commands.
Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Measure-Command, There is no direct equivalent to Unix time command on Windows.

you can also use IBM Data Studio or db2batch tools

**db2batch example;**

```
C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN>db2batch -d <YourDBName> -f C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\select.sql
```

your select.sql should be as below;

```
Select * from tb1;
```

db2batch output;

```
C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN>db2batch -d mydb -f C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\select.sql
* Timestamp: Tue Nov 08 2016 11:17:16 GTB Standard Time
---------------------------------------------

* SQL Statement Number 1:

select * from mytable;

   ...


* Elapsed Time is:       0.013451 seconds

* Summary Table:

Type      Number      Repetitions Total Time (s) Min Time (s)   Max Time (s)   A
rithmetic Mean Geometric Mean Row(s) Fetched Row(s) Output
--------- ----------- ----------- -------------- -------------- -------------- -
-------------- -------------- -------------- -------------
Statement           1           1       0.013451       0.013451       0.013451
      0.013451       0.013451              0             0

* Total Entries:              1
* Total Time:                 0.013451 seconds
* Minimum Time:               0.013451 seconds
* Maximum Time:               0.013451 seconds
* Arithmetic Mean Time:       0.013451 seconds
* Geometric Mean Time:        0.013451 seconds
---------------------------------------------
* Timestamp: Tue Nov 08 2016 11:17:17 GTB Standard Time
```

Comment: Hi sir, can you give me an example syntaxt using this query.. "Select * from tb1"

Comment: you can also use IBM Data Studio tool with gui, take a look at this ;  http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27021964&aid=1